# Rails - can not verify that at least one field is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a class `Prediction` which `belongs_to` either a `currency` or a `market`.

```
  belongs_to :market
  belongs_to :currency

  validate :market_xor_currency?, on: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  def market_xor_currency?
    if(self.market != nil && self.currency != nil)
      false
    end
    true
  end
```

I am testing with Rspec in this manner:

```
p1 = FactoryGirl.create(:prediction)
p1.currency = FactoryGirl.create(:currency)
expect{ p1.market = FactoryGirl.create(:market) }.to raise_error
```

However, the test fails. How can I make `Prediction` belong to either a `currency` or a `market`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a polymorphic relation is more suitable for a such relation

```
class Market < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :predictions, as: :predictable
end

class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :predictions, as: :predictable
end

class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :predictable, polymorphic: true
end
```

This way you won't need to validate any thing, because by definition the prediction can only belong to either one of them

[More about polymorphic relations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

if you still want to do it your way, then I think this validation method should work

```
def market_xor_currency?
  unless market.nil? ^ currency.nil?
    errors.add(:base, 'whatever error you want')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me about polymorphic relations. I changed the code, but now I get this error on some other tests: 
       `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column predictions.predictable_type does not exist
       LINE 1: ...ns" WHERE "predictions"."predictable_id" = $1 AND "predictio...
                                                                    ^
       : SELECT  "predictions".* FROM "predictions" WHERE "predictions"."predictable_id" = $1 AND "predictions"."predictable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1`

Comment: yea to set it up you need 2 fields, predictable_type and predictable_id, you need to create a migration to add those two fields, instead of market_id and currency_id

Comment: check the link in my answer you'll find the details

Comment: o and a tip for you, when you have a prediction object, when you say `@prediction.predictable` it will return the object on the other side, if it's a market it will return a market object, and if it's a currency it will return a currency object

Answer (score 0):

In order to make custom method validation, you need to add error if not valid:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Comment: I did as indicated, but still the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should work in your case:

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if(record.market != nil && record.currency != nil)
      record.errors[:name] << 'market xor currency'
    end
  end
end

class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this would help OP with their issue?

Comment: code creates a validator which checks if the selected record has associated market or currency association, if it has both of those validation fails with given error message (xor logic). And later the validator is assigned to the model.